# How to upload video on youtube channel C#

Tags: c#, api, youtube

I have a C# application, that should upload file video on my YouTube Channel, so I have written the following code:

```
        public static string UploadVideo(string FilePath, string Title, string Description)
        {
            YouTubeRequestSettings settings;
            YouTubeRequest request;
            string devkey = "myApiKei";
            string username = "mail@gmail.com";
            string password = "password";
            settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings(" ", devkey, username, password) { Timeout = -1 };
            request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);

            Video newVideo = new Video();

            newVideo.Title = Title;
            newVideo.Description = Description;
            newVideo.Private = true;
            newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = false;

            newVideo.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource(FilePath, "video/mp4");
            Video createdVideo = request.Upload(newVideo);

            return createdVideo.VideoId;
        }
```

I don't know what is my application Name

```
settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings(" ", devkey, username, password) { Timeout = -1 };
```

So when I try to run the application, after few minutes, I received this error:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException verificata
  _HResult=-2146233087
  _message='La chiamata del costruttore sul tipo 'yOUtUBE.MainWindow' corrispondente ai vincoli di associazione specificati ha generato un'eccezione.' numero riga '3' e posizione riga '9'.
  HResult=-2146233087
  IsTransient=false
  Message='La chiamata del costruttore sul tipo 'yOUtUBE.MainWindow' corrispondente ai vincoli di associazione specificati ha generato un'eccezione.' numero riga '3' e posizione riga '9'.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  LineNumber=3
  LinePosition=9
  StackTrace:
       in System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
  InnerException: System.Net.WebException
       _HResult=-2146233079
       _message=Richiesta annullata: Richiesta annullata..
       HResult=-2146233079
       IsTransient=false
       Message=Richiesta annullata: Richiesta annullata..
       Source=System
       StackTrace:
            in System.Net.ConnectStream.CloseInternal(Boolean internalCall, Boolean aborting)
            in System.Net.ConnectStream.System.Net.ICloseEx.CloseEx(CloseExState closeState)
            in System.Net.ConnectStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
            in System.IO.Stream.Close()
            in Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.CopyRequestData()
            in Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.Execute(Int32 retryCounter)
            in Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.Execute()
            in Google.GData.Client.MediaService.EntrySend(Uri feedUri, AtomBase baseEntry, GDataRequestType type, AsyncSendData data)
            in Google.GData.Client.Service.Insert(Uri feedUri, AtomEntry newEntry, AsyncSendData data)
            in Google.GData.Client.Service.Insert[TEntry](Uri feedUri, TEntry entry)
            in Google.GData.YouTube.YouTubeService.Upload(String userName, YouTubeEntry entry)
            in Google.YouTube.YouTubeRequest.Upload(String userName, Video v)
            in Google.YouTube.YouTubeRequest.Upload(Video v)
            in yOUtUBE.MainWindow.UploadVideo(String FilePath, String Title, String Description) in c:\Users\michele.castriotta\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\yOUtUBE\yOUtUBE\MainWindow.xaml.cs:riga 59
            in yOUtUBE.MainWindow..ctor() in c:\Users\michele.castriotta\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\yOUtUBE\yOUtUBE\MainWindow.xaml.cs:riga 28
       InnerException: System.IO.IOException
            _HResult=-2146232800
            _message=Impossibile chiudere il flusso prima che siano stati scritti tutti i byte.
            HResult=-2146232800
            IsTransient=false
            Message=Impossibile chiudere il flusso prima che siano stati scritti tutti i byte.
            Source=System
            StackTrace:
                 in System.Net.ConnectStream.CloseInternal(Boolean internalCall, Boolean aborting)
            InnerException:
```

Can someone suggest me, where is the problem?